# How I can filter a array_agg value in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table named `jobs`:

```
id PK Serial
model String
model_id UNSIGNED Integer
status String
created_at timestamp
prosessed_at timestamp
```

And foreach model Id I record each status in an array:

```
select
 model_id,
 model,
 array_agg(id) as jobs,
 array_agg(statuses) as statuses
from jobs
group by model,model_id
```

And I use that as a subquery in order to detect any malfucntion in prosessed jobs:

```
select
 *
from (
  select
   model_id,
   model
   array_agg(id) as jobs,
   array_agg(statuses) as statuses
  from jobs
  group by model,model_id
) as jobs
where
    'aborted' in statuses
and
    'pending' not in statuses
and
    'failed' not in statuses
and
    'processed' not in statuses;
```

But in the following line:

```
    'aborted' in statuses
```

Has some sort syntax error:

```
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "statuses"
  Position: 312
```

Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Please have a look at: [Minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You have a number of syntax errors in your query:**

- Missing comma after `model`
- The base column is called `status` not `statuses`
- You can't write `in statuses`, you need to `unnest` the array like this:
  `in (select * from unnest(statuses))`
  Or this:
  `in any (unnest(statuses))`

So your query becomes:

```
select
 *
from (
  select
   model_id,
   model,
   array_agg(id) as jobs,
   array_agg(status) as statuses
  from jobs
  group by model,model_id
) as jobs
where
    'aborted' in any (unnest(statuses))
and
    'pending' not in any (unnest(statuses))
and
    'failed' not in any (unnest(statuses))
and
    'processed' not in any (unnest(statuses));
```

**However, there is a much easier way of writing this.**

You can use conditional counts in a `having` clause:

```
select
   model_id,
   model,
   array_agg(id) as jobs,
   array_agg(status) as statuses
from jobs
group by model, model_id
having
    count(*) filter (where status = 'aborted') > 0
and
    count(*) filter (where status = 'pending') = 0
and
    count(*) filter (where status = 'failed') = 0
and
    count(*) filter (where status = 'processed') = 0;
```

Comment: `'aborted' in (select * from unnest(statuses))` can be simplified to `'aborted' = any(statuses)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Didn't know that works in Postgres, you can't do that with SQL Server

Comment: You can't do `unnest()` in SQL Server either ;) or use arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The parentheses around the right-hand-side of the IN argument are mandatory.  However, what goes in those parentheses must be a list.  An array doesn't work (unless the thing on the left-hand-side is also an array, then you are testing for an array in a list-of-arrays).  To test array membership, you can use the `'aborted'=ANY(...)` construct instead of `IN`.  But does any of this have to do with json_agg, which you are not using?